# Split the contents of Combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have a combobox the allow for multiple entries that are delimited with comas.

Trying to split those values into an array.  Using the following:

```
Dim LogArray As String
   If AreaCB.Value <> "No Changes Needed" Then
   LogArray = Split(Me.Bay1CB.Value, ",")
   End If
```

If statement bombs with type mismatch. I Tried all kinds of combinations, to no avail.

Comment: Define your LogArray as an array of strings:  `Dim LogArray() as String`

Answer (score 0):

I find it simpler to use a Variant:

```
Dim LogArray As Variant

If AreaCB.Value <> "No Changes Needed" Then
    LogArray = Split(Me!Bay1CB.Value, ",")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple.

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(ini.ReadValue("Schools", "Schools").Split(",").ToArray)
```

Etc...